# tik4net System.FormatException: 'Value 'established,related,untracked' for property 'ConnectionState(connection-state)' is not in expected format

Tags: c#

I am using the tik4net library to communicate with a mikrotik router. Adding firewall filters to the router is relatively straightforward

```
var filterRule = new FirewallFilter
                    {
                       Action = FirewallFilter.ActionType.Drop,
                       Chain = FirewallFilter.ChainType.Forward

                    };
tikConnection.Save(filterRule);
```

I tried to access the rules i applied using the following

```
var filter = tikConnection.LoadAll<FirewallFilter>();
```

as demonstrated in the official documentation https://github.com/danikf/tik4net/wiki/High-level-API-reading-data  but it keeps throwing

```
System.FormatException: Value 'established,related,untracked' for property 'ConnectionState(connection-state)' is not in expected format 'tik4net.Objects.Ip.Firewall.FirewallFilter+ConnectionStateType
InnerException InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements.
```

Adding connectionStateType like so

```
  var filterRule = new FirewallFilter
                    {
                        Action = FirewallFilter.ActionType.Drop,
                        Chain = FirewallFilter.ChainType.Forward,
                        ConnectionState = FirewallFilter.ConnectionStateType.New

                    };
```

threw the same exception.